# Rewrite this SQL query using scala slick

Tags: mysql, scala, slick

```
class ItemTable(tag: Tag) extends Table[Item](tag, _tableName = "items") {

  def id: Rep[Int] = column[Int]("id", O.PrimaryKey, O.AutoInc)
  def authId: Rep[String] = column[String]("auth_id")
  def productId: Rep[Int] = column[Int]("product_id")
  def position: Rep[Int] = column[Int]("position")

  override def * : ProvenShape[Item] = (id, authId, productId, position) <> ((Item.apply _).tupled, Item.unapply)
}


class ItemService @Inject()(protected val dbConfigProvider: DatabaseConfigProvider)(implicit executionContext: ExecutionContext) {

    private lazy val query = TableQuery[ItemTable]
    def updateItem(item: Item, previousPosition: Int): Future[Item] = {

        if (previousPosition < item.position) {
          // this is the sql I want to convert to slick
          db.run(sqlu""" UPDATE #${query.baseTableRow.tableName} SET position = position - 1 WHERE position >= #$previousPosition AND position <= #${item.position} AND auth_id = '#${item.authId}'""")
        }
        else if (previousPosition > item.position) {
          db.run(sqlu""" UPDATE #${query.baseTableRow.tableName} SET position = position + 1 WHERE position <= #$previousPosition AND position >= #${item.position} AND auth_id = '#${item.authId}' """)
        }
        else {
         // some other code
        }
    }
}

case class Item(id: Int, authId: String, productId: Int, position: Int){}
```

My SQL works, I'm getting stuck here translating it to slick.

```
val q2 = query.filter(f=> f.authId === item.authId && f.position >= previousPosition && f.position <= item.position)
```

// I don't know how to update multiple or pass the result set to the update function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The embedded style of Slick doesn't support dynamic mutating batch updates of the form `SET position = position + 1` ([Slick issue 497](https://github.com/slick/slick/issues/497)).

That means using Plain SQL style you already have is the right approach here.

*An andditional note on idiomatic `sqlu`*: I notice the `sqlu` you have uses "splicing" (`#$` for the table name). That prevents Slick from treating the value as a string, which is appropriate for what you're doing.  But the later usage `#$previousPosition` would be more typically written as a plain substitution, `$previousPosition`. That's because you'd typically want a SQL parameter there to be correctly escaped by Slick. It probably won't make a difference for integers, but could for other data types.

Comment: I'm starting to see why scala developer prefer raw sql over slick.